# I can't download flutter to vs code. How do I install VSIX manually?

Tags: android, visual-studio, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

When I select "Try Download Manually", "Once downloaded, please manually install the downloaded VSIX of 'dart-code.flutter'." I see this eror.How can I install VSIX manually?

[image]

Comment: which extension (URL) are you trying to install and what has `fabiospampinato` to do with it

Answer (score 0):

Solve the problem with manual installation. It happened like this;

For Flutter Installation: I downloaded the flutter file from https://www.vsixhub.com/vsix/1923/ and clicked the manual install button from the vs code program. Then I selected the file I downloaded and the installation is complete.

For Dart Installation:
I got it via this link: https://www.vsixhub.com/vsix/1145/